# Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline - mvn is not recognized as a command

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I'd like to setup a simple Multibranch Pipeline for my Spring Boot project. I've created such a Multibranch Pipeline in Jenkins, wired in my GitHub repo where I've pushed a very basic Jenkinsfile with a simple step:

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Build with unit testing') {
        steps {
            bat 'mvn clean package'
        }
    }
}
}
```

However Jenkins doesn't seem to understand the mvn command, because I get the following message in my build:

> 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

In went to the Global Tool Configuration where I tried to specify a Maven installation, but regardless of what I do this configuration doesn't seem to persist (I add my Maven, click Apply/Save, go out and come back to this screen again, and the Maven section is empty again, displaying only the "Maven installations..." button. I guess this is the issue. I've read somewhere that this is a Jenkins bug? But could really decode the solution regarding how to solve this in my Jenkinsfile).

Do you guys have any tips how to overcome this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the official jenkins docs, you need to declare maven in **tools** section:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        maven 'Maven 3.3.9'
        jdk 'jdk8'
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Initialize') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    echo "PATH = ${PATH}"
                    echo "M2_HOME = ${M2_HOME}"
                '''
            }
        }

        stage ('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean package' 
            }
            post {
                success {
                    junit 'target/surefire-reports/**/*.xml' 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/07/declarative-maven-project/

I think your are in windows, so change:

```
sh 'mvn clean package'
```

to

```
bat 'mvn clean package'
```

Also the **initialize step** could help you to determine if your jenkins is properly configured.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise, based on the documentation, that it's necessary to explicitely list the tools in a separate section. That solved the issue.

Comment: You are welcome. If this helped to solve your problem, please use the checkmark on the left to mark this as solved and/or an upvote.